# How to remove spaces from strings from a vector in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, gsub

Heyo!

I'm using the function from gsub to delete spaces from a vector. However, in addition to succesfully deleting spaces, it's adding backslashes... I wonder how I can avoid this.

Example

```
"1 000", "10 000", "11 000"
```

Turns into

```
"\1000"\, "\10000"\, "\11000"
```

This is the code:

```
data <- read.csv2('~/Desktop/rProgramming/SurveyPractice/leeftijd-nl.csv')

a <- data[2]

test <- data[2]

c <- gsub(" ", "", test, fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Code works fine, try: `gsub(" ", "", c("1 000", "10 000", "11 000"), fixed = TRUE)`. Please provide reproducible example input: `dput(head(data))`

Comment: I think it might be because that is a vector, mine is a list

Comment: Try `test <- data[[2]]`.

Comment: Because `[` subsets a list whereas `[[` extracts an element from a list. Study `help("[")`.